# Active Directory list all primary domain controllers

Tags: amazon-ec2, active-directory

In PowerShell, I can only run this command

```
Get-ADDomainController -Discover -Site "Default-First-Site-Name"
```

which works but is only returning 1 primary domain controller. I want it to list everything out with something like

```
Get-ADDomainController -Filter *
```

or

```
Get-ADDomainController -Filter * -Server <domain>
```

but these error out with the following message:

> Get-ADDomainController : Unable to contact the server. This may be because this server does not exist, it is currently  down, or it does not have the Active Directory Web Services running.

Anything you'd recommend I can try?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Get-ADDomainController -Filter * | Select hostname, site
```

you use the `|` to get only the values you want from the entire object, which sometimes can look like one result although you have more than one.